# setSuggestionAdapter not displaying text, though the List gets displayed

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, searchview, matrixcursor

I have used the Google places API to retrieve results through the implementation of setOnQueryTextListener  of the searchView widget, then I am  creating a SimpleCursorAdapter by using the results from the places API and setting it as suggestion adapter for the search view. The problem is that the adapter gets assigned and the List is displayed but the data is missing from the suggestion list.

Here is the code:

Activity Class

```
public static  SearchView shopSearchView = null;
shopSearchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
shopSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PlacesAutoComplete pl = new PlacesAutoComplete();
            pl.autocomplete(newText);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

    });
```

---

```
public class PlacesAutoComplete {

      public  static ServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;      //Retrofit Service Endpoint
      public static JsonArray placesPrediction = new JsonArray();

      public void autocomplete(String input) {

        final String[] columnNames = {"_id","description"};
        final MatrixCursor suggestionCursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("&input=" + input);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:in");
        String url = sb.toString();

        //using retrofit to get the data
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(url)       
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .build();

        serviceProvider = restAdapter.create(ServiceProvider.class);

        serviceProvider.getPlacesSuggestion(new Callback<JsonObject>(){

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError response) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void success(JsonObject result, Response response) {
                placesPrediction = result.getAsJsonArray("predictions");
                for (int i = 0; i < placesPrediction.size(); i++) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    PlacePrediction place= gson.fromJson(placesPrediction.get(i),      PlacePrediction.class);

                    suggestionCursor.addRow(new Object[]{i,place.getDescription()});
                    //suggestionCursor is populated with the data. I can see the data while debugging.

                }
                int[] to = {R.id.name_entry};
                SimpleCursorAdapter  suggestionAdapter  = new   SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item,suggestionCursor , new String[]{columnNames[1]},to, 0);


               Activity.shopSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionAdapter);
               //adapter is set, it is visible but the text is not shown
        }

    });






}
```

}

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/> <!--list_item.xml-->
```

Comment: see CursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider() method

Comment: setFilterQueryProvider() in my understanding is used for filtering the results.How would it be used here?

Comment: just set SCA to your SearchView, you can pass null Cursor in SCA constructor, then call SCA.setFilterQueryProvider and in your FilterQueryProvider.runQuery return your MatrixCursor (note you dont need any background threads or async request as runQuery is called in the worker thread)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i added the SCA's setFilterQueryProvider and returned the MatrixCursor in the runquery method, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: is `runQuery` being called? is the returned `Cursor` non empty? what actually doesn't work?

Comment: runQuery is getting called, the cursor returned is non empty, all of this works i can see a list but without text.

Comment: your from.length == 2 but to.length == 1 in SCA ctor

Comment: my bad yes that was the mistake. you can type it as an answer so that i can mark.